# Acceptance tests failing due to record inFlight with ember-data 1.13.4

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've just updated ember-data from 1.0-beta-18 to 1.13.4 and fixed all issues except this one that occurs during my acceptance tests when I try to `destroy` the application in my `afterEach`.

```
Error: Assertion Failed: You can only unload a record which is not inFlight. `<frontend@model:user::ember2881:null>`
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (http://192.168.56.101:4200/assets/vendor.js:25627:21)
    at Object._emberMetalCore.default.assert (http://192.168.56.101:4200/assets/vendor.js:15879:13)
    at Object.ember$data$lib$system$model$states$$assertAgainstUnloadRecord [as unloadRecord] (http://192.168.56.101:4200/assets/vendor.js:80625:13)
    at InternalModel.ember$data$lib$system$model$internal$model$$InternalModel.send (http://192.168.56.101:4200/assets/vendor.js:82563:34)
    at InternalModel.ember$data$lib$system$model$internal$model$$InternalModel.unloadRecord (http://192.168.56.101:4200/assets/vendor.js:82441:14)
    at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.unloadAll (http://192.168.56.101:4200/assets/vendor.js:84142:20)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.unloadAll (http://192.168.56.101:4200/assets/vendor.js:84133:48)
    at ember$data$lib$system$store$$Service.extend.willDestroy (http://192.168.56.101:4200/assets/vendor.js:85034:14)
```

When I deactivate a route in the application I do a `user.save()` which causes a xhr to go out, and is triggering this failure on the application destroy. Removing the `user.save()`. I have tried updating to the latest `ember-cli-qunit` and `ember-qunit` with no luck.

My `afterEach` looks like the following -

```
afterEach: function () {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
    ajaxMock.shutdown();
}
```

Prior to the upgrade this was not an issue. How can I fix or work around this issue?

Comment: Currently working around the issue with `try { Ember.run(application, 'destroy'); } catch(e){ Ember.run(application, 'destroy'); };`

Answer (score 0):

We ran into something similar. We had actually defined a `destroy` method on one of our objects (a session service), inadvertently overriding Ember.Object's `destroy`. Renaming this to something else (`terminate` in our case) fixed the issue.